# How do I access the session in order to do a rewrite?

Tags: asp.net, session, url-rewriting, rewritepath

I'm trying to use the `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` method to serve up different versions of an application to different customers.  I would love to be able to look at the `HttpContext.Current.Session` object to know who it is making the request.  Oddly when I go to look at this at the `BeginRequest` handler, the Session always shows null.  I've tried various other events and have had no luck.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you sure the [`SessionStateModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.aspx) is loaded in your application? I am assuming IIS 7.x, BTW, as you did not specify.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [ASP.Net Application Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) and the [Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) pages on the MSDN.

I believe you can do what you're wanting to do by hooking into the Session_OnStart event, which is fired any time a new session is created.